# my wii had a wrap on it but the surface is now rough

Tags: nintendo-wii

my wii had a wrap on it, I took it off but now the surface is rough is there anyway to make it smooth again ?

Comment: An easy way to remove sticker residue is with rubbing alcohol. DO NOT put it directly on the Wii, put it on a towel then start wiping. You may have to go over it a few times to get it completely off.

Comment: @C-dizzle I would make this an answer. Despite the OP not being super clear on what's going on, this seems the most likely solution (hah).

Comment: @Kaizerwolf nice pun... solution... lol

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to remove sticker residue is with rubbing alcohol. DO NOT put it directly on the Wii, put it on a towel then start wiping. You may have to go over it a few times to get it completely off.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_d0qwDRE-I) of someone doing it on a vehicle as an example. I just did the same thing this past weekend removing a sticker off my windshield with rubbing alcohol.